# Power Automate bug

Tags: power-automate

Situation - I have encountered bug in Power Automate connector "SharePoint" action "List folders" behavior.

Detailed description - action second argument "File Identifier" is a relative path to file. It can be picked via GUI where you can navigate site structure and pick folder through path. Upon clicking target folder, argument input field gets populated with path. It is simple text field.. or so I thought. If such value is provided manually, it throws error. Only if value is encoded, it passes validation. See screenshots below.

Problem - manually entered path is not escaped, therefore invalid. This is NOT acceptable, since argument is an open input field that allows manual data entry.

[image]

[image]

Question - where to report the issue/bug?
I see community forum with discussions or "idea board", but I am interesed that Microsoft takes care of this inconsistent action behavior and forum does not seems to be a good fit.

---

Contacted MS support - posted in idea portal. 
Link to the post : https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/idea/7e31d2b2-e190-ed11-a81c-0022484f1e1d

Comment: Action source code : https://pastebin.com/XHSgzwER (exported from solution, all created in Power Automate site)

Comment: Did you try Googling your answer?  

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/contact-microsoft-office-support-fd6bb40e-75b7-6f43-d6f9-c13d10850e77#:~:text=Sign%20in%20to%20Microsoft%20365,%2Dfree%2C%20US%20only).

Comment: Yep, tried. Unfortunately your link requires "admin account" to open such ticket. Not viable in this case.

Comment: Well that's how you do it so you'll need to get someone who has admin access on your tenant to do it for you.

Comment: This seems like a support request rather than a programming question. Not very adequate for this forum.